# How big is Waves testNet

Tags: nodes, blockchain

I'm setting up for the first time a test node on the **Waves Blockchain**. And now that I started the waves.jar applications with the **`waves-testnet.conf`** file, it seems my computer is downloading a blockchain. I looked on google for the following 2 questions but it seems that we are still in the early stages for waves and there aren't many tutorials online yet to help. So here they are:

1. Am I downloading a separate blockchain from the Main Net?
2. How many blocks does this blockchain have? Where can I check it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is old, and you obviously now know the answer, but I'll still write one for those who need it.

- You are downloading a separate blockchain, *testnet* blockchain, which is different from *mainnet* blockchain. It's made in this way for testing purposes. For testing WAVES can easily be aquired, and thus test transactions should not be mixed with real ones.
- The current height of *testnet* blockchain you can check at https://testnet.wavesexplorer.com/